# Open a new tab and run javascript in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about javascript and jquery.

I have a scenario like this:

1. I have to download a file by sending a POST request to the server. I did this using an invisible form which added to the HTML using jquery.
2. My page of download has an implicit refresh build in by legacy code and I cannot change that.
3. The problem is that when I try to add the invisible form to the page, the refresh happens and takes my form away.

I am thinking whether I can open a new tab, add my download invisible form, send the request and close the tab using some smart javascript. I am very new to this area, please help.

Comment: No, you can't. There's no way to use JavaScript to highjack a user's browser in this way, **thankfully**.

Comment: @Teemu Uh, every remotely modern browser prevents opening and closing of arbitrary windows without user interaction. "Popup blockers" are now built into all the major browsers specifically to prevent this kind of thing... Even IE prevents this kind of outright abuse of the browser, since like version 7.

Comment: @meagar Hmm... Looks like I didn't realize OP wanted to do this "silently". Going to remove my stupid comments in a minute... Done.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `[target]` attribute to your `<form>` and it will make the request in a new page rather than over the existing page that contains the `<form>`.

`[target="_blank"]` would probably work, but if this ends up causing too many pages to be created, you could use a named page so that only one download page is created (`[target="downloadpage"]`).

Alternatively you could try generating your POST request via the `XmlHttpRequest` object.